# spark read hdfs SequenceFile

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

```
JavaPairRDD = newAPIHadoopFile(filePath,SequenceFileInputFormat.class ...)
// transform the JavaPairRDD to JavaNewHadoopRDD
// and use the function mapPartitionWithInputSplit
```

When I run the program, sometimes an error occurs:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -15
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.sync(SequenceFile.java:2695)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(NewHadoopRDD.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$NewHadoopMapPartitionsWithSplitRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please add more details, what is the rest of the code you're running? Versions of Spark and HDFS and so on.

Comment: Hadoop Version:2.7.2,Spark Version:2.2.1  Code:        JavaPairRDD<NullWritable, BytesWritable> logData = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(logFile, SequenceFileInputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, BytesWritable.class, conf);
        JavaNewHadoopRDD<NullWritable, BytesWritable> hadoopRDD = (JavaNewHadoopRDD) logData;
        JavaRDD<String> rdd = hadoopRDD.mapPartitionsWithInputSplit(...);

Comment: error was happened JavaNewHadoopRDD<NullWritable, BytesWritable> hadoopRDD = (JavaNewHadoopRDD) logData,I Don't know why？

Comment: Huff, add this info in your original post, format the stack/code, add more code.

Comment: please add more details ,question title and description is not so much clear,